# How do I fix this Uncaught ArgumentCountError message on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

> Wordpress Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_add_inline_script(), 0 passed in

I have updated all themes and plugins and wordpress. Then I got this error message and cannot access my website.

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_add_inline_script(), 0 passed in /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5865 and at least 2 expected in /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php:130 Stack trace: #0 /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(5865): wp_add_inline_script() #1 /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-scripts.php(502): _doing_it_wrong('WP_Scripts::loc...', 'The `$l10n...', '(This message w...') #2 /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(221): WP_Scripts->localize('wpcom-block-edi...', 'wpcomBlockEdito...', 'https://helloem...') #3 /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/full-site-editing/wpcom-block-editor-nux/class-wpcom-block-editor-nux.php(60): wp_localize_script('wpcom-block-edi...', 'wpcomBlockEdito...', in /home/u160325462/domains/helloembryo.co.uk/public_html/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php on line 130`

Line 5868 reads

```
wp_add_inline_script()
        );
```

Line 130 reads

function wp_add_inline_script( $handle, $data, $position = 'after' ) {
_wp_scripts_maybe_doing_it_wrong( **FUNCTION**, $handle );

```
if ( false !== stripos( $data, '</script>' ) ) {
    _doing_it_wrong(
        __FUNCTION__,
        sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: <script>, 2: wp_add_inline_script() */
            __( 'Do not pass %1$s tags to %2$s.' ),
            '<code>&lt;script&gt;</code>',
            '<code>wp_add_inline_script()</code>'
        ),
        '4.5.0'
    );
    $data = trim( preg_replace( '#<script[^>]*>(.*)</script>#is', '$1', $data ) );
}

return wp_scripts()->add_inline_script( $handle, $data, $position );
```

}

Comment: Which wordpress version do you have now? In 6.2.2 there is no such function on line 5868…